# Do I really have to place my wallet file in the data directory?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, security, bitcoin-qt-setup

I run bitcoin-core QT and I downloaded the **full ledger data to an external HD** so I can move between machines. My wallet.dat file is secured someplace else.

I start-up the QT client giving the external hard disk as the data root.

So **after I put my real wallet.dat file in the data directory** (and restart the client with `-rescan`):

*Do I really have to keep it in the directory where the ledger data is saved? Is that safe?*

Comment: You can use the `-wallet=<path>` startup option to specify a custom path to your wallet.

Comment: @darosior Is this the recommended approach when one wants to have the ledger data in a separate place? please add an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: It seems to me to be the most straightforward one. Added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your wallet database (file) to be in a different directory than your data directory, you can use the `-wallet=<path>` startup option to specify a custom path to your wallet.

Quoting the manpage:

> -wallet=< path >
> Specify wallet database path. Can be specified multiple times to
> load multiple wallets. Path is interpreted relative to  <wallet‐
> dir>  if  it is not absolute, and will be created if it does not
> exist (as a directory  containing  a  wallet.dat  file  and  log
> files).  For backwards compatibility this will also accept names
> of existing data files in .)